# Creating subsets of a data frame, saving output to workplace, and dynamically naming data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame which needs to be subset-ed into 20 unique data frames based on a categorical variable. I am aware that you are able to do so by utilizing the "subset" function as such:

df.# <- subset(df,categorical_variable == #)

However, I would like to automate this process by creating a a function which loops through the possible range of responses in the categorical variable (1:20), dynamically setting the name of the data frame, and creating subsets based on the current value of "i."

Here is a stylized version of what I would want:

```
create_subsets <- function(df) {
                  x <- 1:20
                  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
                      paste(df,x[i],sep=".") <<- subset(df,categorical_variable == x[i])
                  }
              }
```

I understand that the above function is impossible, specifically the section where I set the paste function equal the subset function-the point is to illustrate my aim. How can I dynamically name the subsets, and save them to the workplace?

Thank you.

Comment: Would `split()` get what you're looking for?

Comment: ssp3nc3r, I am not familiar with this function, how would I implement it into my current problem?

Comment: The following code splits one data frame into as many as you specify by a factor:  `d <- data.frame(a = factor(rep(LETTERS, 10)), b = runif(260, 0, 100)); split(x = d, f = d$a)`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I cannot see how we can dynamically name the lists.

Comment: `split` produces a named list, with the names corresponding to the values of the splitting variable.

Comment: This worked: 
function(df) {
    x <- 1:20
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        list2env(x = split(df,df$categorical_variable), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: @Jeremias - you don't need the `for` loop.